# How can I get last transaction on S3 bucket?

Tags: upload, amazon-s3, filesize

Am a beginner of S3 AWS SDK. and getting problem in my project.

I want to get uploaded or downloaded size of file which is currently uploaded. Actually the functionality of my application is that it will upload contents directly from client browser to Amazon S3. But if transfer of data interrupted and if exception is raised then i cant track that how much data of file has be transferred.

Comment: If this is a programming question, you may want to try http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

If data transfer is interrupted you will have to start all over. There is no way to resume the transfer where you left off. check out [Amazon S3 official forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=161238#161238) for more info.